# Why if I show that that $f(x-1)$ is irreduction, so $f(x)$ is also irreductible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I have to show that $f(x)=x^4+4x^3+6x^2+2x+1$ is irreductible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. With Eisenstein's criterion, why if I show that that $f(x-1)$ is irreducible, so $f(x)$ is also irreducible? It is important to know that $f(x-1)=x^4-2x+2$ and works with Eisenstein's criterion.

Comment: If you shift the graph of a function one unit horizontally, you change its zeros by one unit as well. So the new function will be irreducible if the original one was irreducible.

Comment: If $f(x+a)$ is irreducible in general (for some $a\in \mathbb{Z}$, then $f(x)$ is also irreducible: if $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$, then $f(x+a)=g(x+a)h(x+a)$, therefore $g(x+a),~h(x+a)$ are constant, from the irreducibility of $f(x)$, i.e. $g(x),~h(x)$ are constant, as desired.

Answer (score 3):

$f(x) =g(x)h(x)$ where $g,h$ are polynomials of degree less than $\deg f$ if and only if 
$$f(x-1)=g(x-1)h(x-1).$$

Hence $f(x)$ is reducible if and only if $f(x-1)$ is.

Therefore, since Eisenstein's criterion tells us that $f(x-1)$ is irreducible, we deduce that $f(x)$ is irreducible.

Comment: Could you prove $\Longleftarrow )$?

Comment: Write $F(x)= f(x-1)$, and similarly for $g,h$. Then $f(x) =F(x+1)= G(x+1)H(x+1) =g(x)h(x)$. All of this just comes down to translating the polynomial by an integer.